# Passing Json string to Json.NET in C# and get it back as VBA Object

Tags: c#, json, excel, vba, json.net

until now, I have been using the vba-json parser from github. Due to the appearance of large JSON-Files, I realized, that the vba-json parser needs a very long time, because it reads the json strings character by character and transforms them into a vba collection.

Now, I researched a bit in the internet and found JSON.NET, which appears to be a very fast json parser. To use this in Excel-VBA, I installed Visual Studio and created a VSTO-Project.

I succeeded in passing the json-string from the vba-code to Visual Studio. The Json-String is then deserialized into a C#-Object. Now, when I return the C#-Object back to Excel VBA, I get an error message stating

> Error 424 Object required

My JSON-File I want to work with in Excel-VBA:

```
[
  {
    "rootarray": [
      {
        "id": "11234",
        "price": 2.99
      },
      {
        "id": "5324",
        "price": 32.99
      },
      {
        "id": "23",
        "price": 5.99
      }
   ],
   "name" : "Shop Nr. 22"
  }
]
```

My VBA-Code:

```
Sub NetTest(strJson As String)
    Dim addIn As COMAddIn
    Dim objekt As Object
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ExcelAddIn2")
    Set objekt = addIn.Object

    Dim solution As Object
    Set solution = objekt.CSharpToVBA(strJson)
End Sub
```

And my C#-Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Object = System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace ExcelAddIn2
{

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public class CodeKlasse
    {
        public partial class Welcome
        {
            [JsonProperty("rootarray")]
            public Rootarray[] Rootarray { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Rootarray
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("price")]
            public double Price { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome[]>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }

        public Welcome[] CSharpToVBA(string jsontext)
        {
            try
            {
                var jPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome[]>(jsontext, Converter.Settings);
                return jPerson;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                var failure = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome[]>(string.Empty);
                return failure;
            }
        }


    }

    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private CodeKlasse codeKlasse;

        protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
        {
            codeKlasse = new CodeKlasse();
            return codeKlasse;
        }
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region Von VSTO generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Apparently, Excel can't work with the C# Object. How do I do this. I want the C# Object transformed into a vba object, so that when I write in Excel-VBA:

`?solution(0)("rootarray")(2)("price")`

I get the value:

`5.99`

I hope anyone can help me? I would appreciate it a lot.
Thank you.

Greetings.

Comment: Why are `Welcome` and `RootArray`partial and nested? Move them out of `CodeKlasse` and add the `ComVisible` attribute to them as well. I don't think partial does any harm, but it does do anything good either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I put my json code here: [link](https://app.quicktype.io/)  and got the c# code from there. As far As I understand, in the method `CSharpToVBA` I create the variable `jPerson`, which deserializes the json into the `Welcome[]` object and the partial classes `Welcome` and `RootArray` define what `Welcome[]` exactly is?

Comment: Partial is a trick to be able to declare part of a class in one spot and the remaining part in another. In the quicktype.io example it is used to declare a static `FromJson` method on `Welcome`. About the classes being defined inside CodeKlasse I still think you need to move them out and make them ComVisible in their own right.

Comment: Ok, I moved `Welcome` and `Rootarray` out of `Codeklasse` , but my issue still remains, as soon as I return `jPerson` to Excel, it does not recognize it as a vba-object, do you have any Idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/Interop/TestServer_2.aspx does this article help?